# How to search inside multiple indices using Nest ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have two indices with the following mapping(I will shortcut their mappings):

1) AccountType mapping:

```
 elasticClient.CreateIndex("account", i => i
                .Settings(s => s
                          .NumberOfShards(2)
                          .NumberOfReplicas(0)
                          )
                          .Mappings(m => m
                                    .Map<AccountType>(map => map
                                               .AutoMap()
                                               .Properties(p => p
                                                    .Text(c => c
                                                           .Name(n => n.Name)
                                                           .Analyzer("standard")
                                                    )
                                                    .Text(c => c
                                                           .Name(n => n.Description)
                                                           .Analyzer("standard")
                                                    )
                                                )
                                    )
                            )
                          );
```

2) ProductType mapping:

```
 elasticClient.CreateIndex("proudct", i => i
                .Settings(s => s
                          .NumberOfShards(2)
                          .NumberOfReplicas(0)
                          )
                          .Mappings(m => m
                                    .Map<ProductType>(map => map
                                               .AutoMap()
                                               .Properties(p => p
                                                    .Text(c => c
                                                           .Name(n => n.Title)
                                                           .Analyzer("standard")
                                                    )
                                                    .Text(c => c
                                                           .Name(n => n.Description)
                                                           .Analyzer("standard")
                                                    )
                                                )
                                    )
                            )
                          );
```

Now I have several things I need to get them clear:

1) First is it a good idea to have one index which in my case is account and has products as nested objects, but here for each time I want to update/add new product I have to re-index(update) the whole account document?

2) My second questions is: I want to have search functionality, so if the user search by typing in a textbox I would like to get best matches for both Accounts and Products(here I will search against product's title and description plus account's name and description then getting best matches) :

So here how to search against multiple indices using **Nest ElasticSeach**, or if it's not possible is it a good idea to get best matches from every index, then getting best matches from both results depending on score?

PS:
Here is an example for searching inside product index:

```
        var result = elasticClient.Search<ProductType>(s => s
                                            .Size(10)
                                            .Query(q => q
                                              .MultiMatch(m => m
                                                .Fields(f => f.Field(p => p.Title, 1.5).Field(p => p.Description, 0.8))
                                                .Operator(Operator.Or)
                                                .Query(query)
                                              )
                                            )
                                          );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1) First is it a good idea to have one index which in my case is account and has products as nested objects, but here for each time I want to update/add new product I have to re-index(update) the whole account document?

It's generally recommended to have one type per index, and [in Elasticsearch 6.0+, you can only have one type per index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html). If products are represented as nested objects on an account then adding a new product to an account will require updating the whole document (*either in your application code, or within Elasticsearch*).

> 2) My second questions is: I want to have search functionality, so if the user search by typing in a textbox I would like to get best matches for both Accounts and Products(here I will search against product's title and description plus account's name and description then getting best matches) :

You can search across multiple indices, check out [the documentation of covariant search results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/covariant-search-results.html); it shows an example of returning multiple different types from one index (this example will be updated for 6.0!), but it's possible to perform this across multiple indices. Here's an example:

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
        .InferMappingFor<AccountType>(i => i
            .IndexName("account")
        )
        .InferMappingFor<ProductType>(i => i
            .IndexName("product")
        )
        // useful for development, to make the request/response bytes
        // available on the response
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
        // indented JSON in requests/responses
        .PrettyJson()
        // log out all requests/responses
        .OnRequestCompleted(callDetails =>
        {
            if (callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri} \n" +
                    $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.RequestBodyInBytes)}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{callDetails.HttpMethod} {callDetails.Uri}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            if (callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                         $"{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(callDetails.ResponseBodyInBytes)}\n" +
                         $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Status: {callDetails.HttpStatusCode}\n" +
                         $"{new string('-', 30)}\n");
            }
        });

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists("account").Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex("account");

    client.CreateIndex("account", i => i
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(2)
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<AccountType>(map => map
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(c => c
                        .Name(n => n.Name)
                        .Analyzer("standard")
                    )
                    .Text(c => c
                        .Name(n => n.Description)
                        .Analyzer("standard")
                   )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    if (client.IndexExists("product").Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex("product");

    client.CreateIndex("product", i => i
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(2)
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<ProductType>(map => map
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(c => c
                        .Name(n => n.Title)
                        .Analyzer("standard")
                    )
                    .Text(c => c
                        .Name(n => n.Description)
                        .Analyzer("standard")
                   )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.IndexMany(new[] {
        new AccountType { Name = "Name 1", Description = "Description 1" },
        new AccountType { Name = "Name 2", Description = "Description 2" },
        new AccountType { Name = "Name 3", Description = "Description 3" },
        new AccountType { Name = "Name 4", Description = "Description 4" },
    });

    client.IndexMany(new[] {
        new ProductType { Title = "Title 1", Description = "Description 1" },
        new ProductType { Title = "Title 2", Description = "Description 2" },
        new ProductType { Title = "Title 3", Description = "Description 3" },
        new ProductType { Title = "Title 4", Description = "Description 4" },
    });

    var indices = Indices.Index(typeof(ProductType)).And(typeof(AccountType));

    client.Refresh(indices);

    var searchResponse = client.Search<object>(s => s
        .Index(indices)
        .Type(Types.Type(typeof(ProductType), typeof(AccountType)))
        .Query(q => (q
            .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(Infer.Field<ProductType>(ff => ff.Title, 1.5))
                    .Field(Infer.Field<ProductType>(ff => ff.Description, 0.8))
                )
                .Operator(Operator.Or)
                .Query("Title 1")
            ) && +q
            .Term("_index", "product")) || (q
            .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(Infer.Field<AccountType>(ff => ff.Name, 3))
                    .Field(Infer.Field<AccountType>(ff => ff.Description, 0.3))
                )
                .Operator(Operator.Or)
                .Query("Name 4")
            ) && +q
            .Term("_index", "account"))
        )
    );

    foreach (var document in searchResponse.Documents)
        Console.WriteLine($"document is a {document.GetType().Name}");
}

public class ProductType
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class AccountType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The result is

```
document is a AccountType
document is a ProductType
document is a AccountType
document is a ProductType
document is a AccountType
document is a AccountType
document is a ProductType
document is a ProductType
```

There's a lot going on here so let me explain. The search request JSON looks like:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/product%2Caccount/producttype%2Caccounttype/_search?pretty=true 
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Title 1",
                  "operator": "or",
                  "fields": [
                    "title^1.5",
                    "description^0.8"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": {
                    "value": "product"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "Name 4",
                  "operator": "or",
                  "fields": [
                    "name^3",
                    "description^0.3"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": {
                    "value": "account"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The search is executed across both the `product` and `account` indices, across `producttype` and `accounttype` types. A multi_match query is performed on the `title` and `description` fields, and this is combined with a term query using a bool query, to constrain the query to the `product` index. The term query is in a filter clause because no relevancy score should be calculated for the term query. This bool query is combined with another bool query that performs a multi_match query on `name` and `description` fields, cmbined with a term query to constrain the query to the `account` index. The two bool queries are combined using should clauses because either one of the bool queries or the other needs to match.

`object` is used as the generic parameter type for the `Search<T>()` method call because `ProductType` and `AccountType` do not share a common base class (besides `object`!) to which the resulting document collection can be typed. We can see however from the results that NEST has actually deserialized documents with type `producttype` to instances of `ProductType` and documents with type `accounttype` to instances of `AccountType`.

The query uses [operator overloading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) to more succinctly combine queries.

Comment: Bro you are the master of Nest elasticsearch. Every time I ask a question I get an accurate answer from you.Thanks a lot  for your too detailed answer .

Comment: Sorry for my bad english. It seems that "like a hell" has bad meaning

Comment: I don't think it's bad, but don't think it translates properly :)