# Search two indexes with specific dependent scenarios using nest and elastisearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have two indices in the elastic search

```
PUT /customers
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "customerId": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "birthday": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /tickets
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ticketId": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "customerId": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "winning": {
        "type": "float"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have two classes for these indices

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; }
        public string Name { get; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; }

        public Customer(int customerId, string name, DateTime birthday)
        {
            CustomerId = customerId;
            Name = name;
            Birthday = birthday;
        }
    }


public class Ticket
    {
        public int TicketId { get; }
        public int CustomerId { get; }
        public decimal Winning { get; }

        public Ticket(int ticketId, int customerId, decimal winning)
        {
            TicketId = ticketId;
            CustomerId = customerId;
            Winning = winning;
        }
    }
```

I have set up the elastic locally and fed it with some documents.
As you can see a customer could have many tickets.

I would like to implement a search query using the nest nuget in .net 7 that

> I want to retrieve the tickets that the customers have birthdays
> before 1990-1-1.

I read some other [cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56478093/full-text-search-with-multiple-index-in-elastic-search-using-nest-c-sharp) but I could not achieve these result

Here is my code that tries to retrieve this info but it fetch only tickets

```
var customersIndex = "customers";
var ticketsIndex = "tickets";
var indices = Indices.Index(customersIndex).And(ticketsIndex);

var response255 = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .Index(indices)
    .Query(q =>
        (q
            .MultiMatch(m => m
                .Fields(f => f
                    .Field(Infer.Field<Ticket>(ff => ff.TicketId))
                    .Field(Infer.Field<Ticket>(ff => ff.Winning))
                )
            ) && +q
            .Term("_index", ticketsIndex)
        ) ||
        (q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Should(sh => sh
                    .Bool(nb => nb
                        .Filter(filter => filter
                            .DateRange(dr => dr
                                .Field(Infer.Field<Customer>(ff => ff.Birthday))
                                .LessThan(new DateTime(1990, 1, 1))
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) && +q
            .Term("_index", customersIndex)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: since Elasticsearch does not support joins have you considered storing denormalized data or just having two queries?

Comment: @BohdanStupak Hello this is my second option denormalization, two different queries or parent-child, but I try to find if missing anything to join two indices. Thanks!