# Source filtering while searching inside multiple indices using Nest ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I followed the instructions to search multiple indices using NEST ElasticSearch mentioned here.

[How to search inside multiple indices using Nest ElasticSearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836986/how-to-search-inside-multiple-indices-using-nest-elasticsearch)

Now I want to select only certain fields per index from the matching results (hits). Is that something that can be built into the query within C# itself ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source filtering applies to the `_source` of all hits from all indices; it's not possible to target the `_source` of hits from specific indices within the body of a single search request.